# what causes com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: java.io.EOFException?

Tags: java, aerospike

What is the cause of this?

```
com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: java.io.EOFException
    at com.aerospike.client.async.SelectorManager.processKey(SelectorManager.java:184) [aerospike-client-3.0.24.jar:?]
    at com.aerospike.client.async.SelectorManager.runCommands(SelectorManager.java:108) [aerospike-client-3.0.24.jar:?]
    at com.aerospike.client.async.SelectorManager.run(SelectorManager.java:69) [aerospike-client-3.0.24.jar:?]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at com.aerospike.client.async.AsyncConnection.read(AsyncConnection.java:127) ~[aerospike-client-3.0.24.jar:?]
    at com.aerospike.client.async.AsyncSingleCommand.read(AsyncSingleCommand.java:48) ~[aerospike-client-3.0.24.jar:?]
    at com.aerospike.client.async.SelectorManager.processKey(SelectorManager.java:164) ~[aerospike-client-3.0.24.jar:?]
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Without any of the code that causes the exception this might as well be a rhetorical question.

Comment: The question is directed at the implementers of aerospike - not a general java question.  I'd appreciate if you could take away your down vote on the question.

Comment: Then you should start with reading the guidelines for posting StackOverflow and edit your question to meet the rules. Whether your question has to do with general Java functions or a library, you can't ask "why am I getting this exception?" if you won't show us what you're doing that's causing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EOFException is thrown when the socket connection is no longer valid.  It usually happens because the server has closed the connection.

```
 /**
 * Read till byteBuffer limit reached or received would-block.
 */
public boolean read(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws IOException {
    while (byteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
        int len = socketChannel.read(byteBuffer);

        if (len == 0) {         
            // Got would-block.
            return false;
        }

        if (len < 0) {
            // Server has shutdown socket.
                throw new EOFException();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: More details regarding the closed connection EOFException can be found in the following Aerospike discussion thread - https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/what-causes-aerospikeexception-java-io-eofexception/444/12

Comment: It *only* happens when the peer has closed the connection. Other problems cause connection resets.