# Aerospike EOFException

Tags: java, exception, key-value-store, aerospike

I have a 4 servers nodes cluster in Aerospike 3.8.4 with Java Client 3.2.2. When I try to save an object, I get this error:

```
error code 0 for key test:docs2:80000001:cd60b46ba665c24e646f74053de2846b2a17f7d0
com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: java.io.EOFException
    at com.aerospike.client.command.SyncCommand.execute(SyncCommand.java:95)
    at com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.put(AerospikeClient.java:339)
    at $line58.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:41)
    at $line58.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line58.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line58.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line58.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:784)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1039)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:636)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:635)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:635)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:567)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:563)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:802)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:836)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:694)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:404)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:424)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:925)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:911)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:911)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:911)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(ILoop.scala:936)
    at xsbt.ConsoleInterface.run(ConsoleInterface.scala:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.console(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
    at sbt.Console.sbt$Console$$console0$1(Console.scala:23)
    at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Console.scala:24)
    at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Console.scala:24)
    at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Console.scala:24)
    at sbt.Logger$$anon$4.apply(Logger.scala:90)
    at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:244)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at com.aerospike.client.cluster.Connection.readFully(Connection.java:100)
    at com.aerospike.client.command.WriteCommand.parseResult(WriteCommand.java:67)
    at com.aerospike.client.command.SyncCommand.execute(SyncCommand.java:57)
    ... 47 more
```

Why is this happening? One thing I noticed is that even with these exceptions, sometimes the objects are actually written to the kvs.

Comment: it's seems same issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184336/what-causes-com-aerospike-client-aerospikeexception-java-io-eofexception

Comment: It may seem the same issue, but I don't think is the same, because this is a write operation, while the other issue is a read operation.

Comment: This needs more information about the object size triggering this error, and a snippet of code.